# Getting an empty value with val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have table with the following id inside one of the rows
`<td class="firstRow"> <span id="randomWordToTranslate"></span></td>`
the `firstRow` class just include padding preferences in css.

In my java script class, I am calling two functions
the first randomly assigned a value to this id , so when I am loading my page I will get a different word each time : this part is working
`$("#randomWordToTranslate").html(current_dict[listOfKeys[Math.floor(Math.random() * listOfKeys.length)]]);`

the second inside a button listener trying to get the value of the word inside this field whenever the button is clicked

```
var spanishWord = $("#randomWordToTranslate");
var inputValue = $(spanishWord).val();
```

but when I doing console.log(inputValue) I am printing an empty row into my log.
Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the `<span>` isn't an `<input>` tag (or other form input like `<select>`), it will not have a `.val()` (value). Instead, you need either `.html()` or `.text()`:

```
var spanishWord = $("#randomWordToTranslate");
var inputValue = spanishWord.text();
// Or:
var inputValue = spanishWord.html();
```

Comment: @freshbm What are we supposed to see? In both FF and Chrome, I get a blank line printed from the `console.log()`.